# Homology functor into an abelian category instead of abelian groups.

Tags: algebraic-topology

All of the Eilenberg-Steenrod axioms for homology can relatively easily be translated into the language of category theory. We can then replace the abelian groups with a general abelian category.

Has this been done before? If not what complications will probably arise doing this? Do more axioms need to be added in order to say anything useful?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have never seen such a generalization, but of course I am not omniscient. I do not see any problems in replacing the category of abelian groups with a general abelian category, but I doubt that it will produce something new.

The Freyd-Mitchell embedding theorem says that for each  (small) abelian category $A$ there exist a ring $R$ and a fully faithful and exact functor $F: A → R$-$Mod$ to the category of left $R$-modules. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mitchell%27s_embedding_theorem. That is, $F$ translates the new kind of homology theory into a "standard" theory.